# Any way to generate a C# HTTPClient wrapper for a WebAPI project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In an upcoming project we are looking to use ASP.NET WebAPI 2 to expose service functionality to both our web sites and browser clients.

Since we want as few "end-points" as possible where possible we want all calls, even "internal" to consume our servers from the WebAPI web services. (i.e. not just new-ing up a controller instance directly)

I am looking for something to help generate or scaffold C# "client's" that wrap the HTTPClient and deliver strongly typed "proxy's".  Similar to WCF when generating proxy's via "Add new service reference".

I have read other questions asking similar things (As seen [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25141/is-there-a-better-way-to-consume-an-asp-net-web-api-call-in-an-mvc-controller)), but wanted to ask a more direct question not related to MVC or testing concerns.

Comment: This is the best representation of what I was looking for:
http://www.faniereynders.com/2013/03/aspnet-web-api.html
Hope this might come out in an official way later...

Comment: Update:AutoRest 
https://github.com/Azure/autorest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the best representation of what I was looking for:

[ASP.NET Web API <#= Proxy to T4 #>](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323033111/http://www.faniereynders.com:80/2013/03/aspnet-web-api.html)

[Introducing WebApiProxy: Providing JavaScript & C# proxies with Intellisense including documentation for ASP.NET Web API](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315050047/http://www.faniereynders.com/2014/01/introducing-webapiproxy-providing.html)

He put his example code up on github:

https://github.com/RestCode/WebApiProxy

Hope this might come out in an official way later.

Answer (score 4):

I am currently working on an open-source Swagger toolchain for .NET. With these tools you can select a Web API controller from an existing DLL and generate a Swagger specification or client code for C# and TypeScript. Using T4 templates in Visual Studio the generation process works like WCF Service References.

Have a look here: http://NSwag.org

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting. How difficult would it be to add VB support?

Comment: This feature is not planned, but there are tools to convert c# to vb.net

Comment: I imagine, now with the advent of Roslyn, that such a step could even be automated. Looks like a good utility you've built here — keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way I've seen of delivering easy to use web api functionality is to have an assembly which defines the main classes as well as some post functionality.  This assembly uses JSON to transfer data.

Take a look at how PayPal's integrated API works.  Essentially they give you an assembly which contains the definitions for the various classes in use.  There is a class for transferring the data to the server.

The idea is that the clients don't care how they are actually communicating with you (it's all in the black box) however they have the option of using the predefined classes or roll their own.

Comment: I believe the main concern there is the mapping between relative uris of various services and corresponding methods so that rather than a generic set of methods accepting uris you got a large set of methods whene a single method corresponds to a single api call. The question is not whether this is possible, apparently it is as such wrapping api can easily be handcoded but how to automatically generate it using an existing approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you don't really need a full blown library to access data; if you have your data objects defined in a common library, you can use generic helper methods to do something like

```
    public static TItem GetItem<TItem>(this HttpClient httpClient, string queryString) where TItem : class
    {
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(queryString).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TItem>().Result;
        }

        throw new HttpRequestException(response.ToString());
    }
```

but change for your own error handling, etc.