# Getting response from console app within web api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, console-application

I have two projects. The first one is made as WEB API, and the second one is Console app.
I am wondering how is it possible to hit one method from Console app while I am hitting web api.

For an example: This is my console project with Test method which I need to call within my web api call:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving messages...");
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return "Some value";
    }
```

My web api method is like:

```
 public class HomeController : ApiController
 {
    public string Get()
    {
        var temp=Test();
        return temp;
    }        
}
```

As a result I want to get "Some value" as I hit the HomeController (GET method).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499970/any-way-to-generate-a-c-sharp-httpclient-wrapper-for-a-webapi-project

Answer (score 0):

I think that i'm not understood as well your question. If you want to receive data from the net you have to write functions that send and receive data and print it to the screen. So you have to study Sockets wich are the 'objects' that allow you to use the net.

Comment: I have a console app which is running all time in the background and whenever I hit the web api, one method in console app gets triggered and returns some result. So, I want to get that result as I hit the web api. Is it better explained now ? Thanks

Comment: And you want to use it as a net app? For example so hit from another computer? Becouse if you are using the net you have to use Sockets which are objects that allow you to connect to other computers and send data via net. So you can use them to hit and tell to your console app what you want to show. Obviously the console app has to implement a method that controll when someone send data all time.